# Install NPM in Visual Studio 2017 through package.json

Tags: node.js, angular, visual-studio, npm

Visual Studio 2017 throwing error when trying to install NPM package through package.json

The content of package.json copied from [quickstart](https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/package.json).

The day before yesterday it was working and installing NPM package in particular project. Today I created new project and trying to download NPM package for newly created project which throwing error

**package.json:-**

```
{
   "name":"angular-quickstart",
   "version":"1.0.0",
   "description":"QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
   "scripts":{
      "build":"tsc -p src/",
      "build:watch":"tsc -p src/ -w",
      "build:e2e":"tsc -p e2e/",
      "serve":"lite-server -c=bs-config.json",
      "serve:e2e":"lite-server -c=bs-config.e2e.json",
      "prestart":"npm run build",
      "start":"concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"npm run serve\"",
      "pree2e":"npm run build:e2e",
      "e2e":"concurrently \"npm run serve:e2e\" \"npm run protractor\" --kill-others --success first",
      "preprotractor":"webdriver-manager update",
      "protractor":"protractor protractor.config.js",
      "pretest":"npm run build",
      "test":"concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
      "pretest:once":"npm run build",
      "test:once":"karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
      "lint":"tslint ./src/**/*.ts -t verbose"
   },
   "keywords":[

   ],
   "author":"",
   "license":"MIT",
   "dependencies":{
      "@angular/common":"~4.3.4",
      "@angular/compiler":"~4.3.4",
      "@angular/core":"~4.3.4",
      "@angular/forms":"~4.3.4",
      "@angular/http":"~4.3.4",
      "@angular/platform-browser":"~4.3.4",
      "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic":"~4.3.4",
      "@angular/router":"~4.3.4",
      "angular-in-memory-web-api":"~0.3.0",
      "systemjs":"0.19.40",
      "core-js":"^2.4.1",
      "rxjs":"5.0.1",
      "zone.js":"^0.8.4"
   },
   "devDependencies":{
      "concurrently":"^3.2.0",
      "lite-server":"^2.2.2",
      "typescript":"~2.1.0",
      "canonical-path":"0.0.2",
      "tslint":"^3.15.1",
      "lodash":"^4.16.4",
      "jasmine-core":"~2.4.1",
      "karma":"^1.3.0",
      "karma-chrome-launcher":"^2.0.0",
      "karma-cli":"^1.0.1",
      "karma-jasmine":"^1.0.2",
      "karma-jasmine-html-reporter":"^0.2.2",
      "protractor":"~4.0.14",
      "rimraf":"^2.5.4",
      "@types/node":"^6.0.46",
      "@types/jasmine":"2.5.36"
   },
   "repository":{

   }
}
```

visual studio error Message:-

```
npm WARN install Couldn't install optional dependency: Unsupported
npm WARN install Couldn't install optional dependency: Unsupported
npm WARN deprecated express@2.5.11: express 2.x series is deprecated
npm WARN deprecated connect@1.9.2: connect 1.x series is deprecated
npm WARN deprecated express@2.5.11: express 2.x series is deprecated
npm WARN deprecated connect@1.9.2: connect 1.x series is deprecated
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
```

Comment: that's all warnings, does your node_modules folder remains empty?

Comment: yes, it is empty...

Comment: please add your node, npm vertsions, does result the same when you run "npm install" from the console? maybe VisualStudio keeps libraries in some other folder.
BTW read the readme of project where from you've get package.json, it's deprecated